# What makes my RDS allocated storage so high?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have databases running on AWS RDS. A lot of event notification says `Storage size 3630 GB is approaching the maximum storage threshold 4000 GB. Increase the maximum storage threshold.`. I've checked all my databases size, it's only around 150 GB. What makes my DB instance auto-scaled that high until 3630 GB? How can I check what is inside my allocated storage?

[image: allocated storage]

I already run query to check my databases size, check autoscale settings, and check automatic backup. I dont know what makes my allocated storage so high. I want to know what makes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check you log file sizes.  Unless you have them stored specifically somewhere else they eat up your allocated storage.  Log files are usually retained for only 72 hours, again unless you specified otherwise.  But if you are generating a lot of errors you can quickly eat up a lot of space.